# a \frac{}{} with knobs

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

What definition code gives mathematics mode output that looks like this?

[image: if]

Often `\(A\) | \(B\)` inline, and `\[\frac{A}{B}\]` in display mode, is the notation for ``A if and only if B''.

If `A \cirf B` inline, and `\fric{A}{B}` in display mode, is the notation for ``A if B'', what is the best way to construct these macros such that:

(a) the `if` is `iff` capped with orthogonal knobs in opposite directions at its ends,

(b) the `if` like `iff` scales with its arguments,

(c) the `if` compiles everywhere the `iff` compiles?

(EDIT: changed `if` to `cirf`.)

Comment: Better think of a name other than `\if`... ;).

Comment: Why? Wouldn't redefining standard TeX macros make the editor of the journal like me even more ;) It'd make their typsetting much harder a job, with all the random compile errors it'd introduce in the issue. Every journal team consists of people who enjoy a challenge...

Comment: If you're not careful, barbara will disappear you ;).

Comment: I think your edit may be a bit too aggressive - I find it hard to understand what is wanted from your updated description.

Comment: Is this better? (My edit before was what I ended up printing.) I am now starting to use this notation in papers and welcome anybody else who wants to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: a solution for fractions; see below.

Here's a solution for the first one (side-by-side, not the fraction), using [rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\hookheight}{8pt}
\newcommand{\hookends}{3.5pt}
\newcommand{\hookthickness}{0.7pt}
\newcommand{\hook}{\mathop{\hbox{%
    \rule{\hookends}{\hookthickness}%
    \rule{\hookthickness}{\hookheight}%
    \hspace{-\hookthickness}%
    \rule[\hookheight]{\hookends}{\hookthickness}%
}}}
\begin{document}
$A \hook B$
\end{document}
```

If you think it should be longer, taller, narrower, etc., you can adjust the parameters `\hookheight`, `\hookthickness`, and `\hookends` (the last one controls the lengths of the knobs). It may also be useful to adjust the spacing on either side.

With these settings, it looks like this:

[image]

For the fraction operator, I was able to adopt a similar approach. Once again, you'll likely have to twiddle it to get the height/spacing/thickness you want, especially if you're using a different font. Additionally, I calibrated it for display fractions; the spacing will be different for text fractions, though the same ideas should apply.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\hfthickness}{0.35pt}
\newcommand{\hfseparator}{4pt}
\newcommand{\hfheight}{6pt}
\newcommand{\fracoffset}{2.35pt}
\newcommand{\hookfrac}[2]{%
    \rule[\fracoffset]{\hfthickness}{\hfheight}
    \rule[\fracoffset]{2pt+\hfseparator}{\hfthickness}
    \hspace{-2pt}
    \frac{#1}{#2}%
    \hspace{-2pt}
    \rule[\fracoffset]{2pt+\hfseparator}{\hfthickness}
    \rule[-\hfheight+\fracoffset+\hfthickness]{\hfthickness}{\hfheight}
}   
\begin{document}
\[\hookfrac{A}{B} = \hookfrac{\int_X A^2 + BX + C}{\sqrt X}\]
\end{document}
```

It looks like this.
[image]

Once again, there are a bunch of parameters you can edit: `\hfthickness` controls the thickness of the knobs, `\hfseparator` determines how far they extend past the fraction, `\hfheight` determines the height of the knobs, and `\fracoffset` is used to move them vertically, to align them with the fraction bar.

There may a better or more general way to do this, but I don't know.

Comment: Great, any idea what to do with the fraction next? The rules would have to change position with the endpoints and height of the bar ...

Comment: I'm working on it! What precisely do you mean by "height of the bar?"

Comment: If I put an integral in the `denominator` the fraction bar starts higher, because B is larger now, and the rules starting at its endpoints would have to rise with it, that's all. Same if B is smaller. We have to detect the coordinates of the fraction in x,y, to position the rules, right? It's can't be relative A with some downward shifts, because A can change in size too. It might be larger or smaller depending on the relation.

Comment: Ok! I just posted a potential solution. If I understand you correctly, my solution works for this (I tested it with `\displaystyle` integrals in place of either of _A_ and _B_ and both). To the best of my understanding, the fraction bar is a fixed baseline in display math.
If this isn't working for you, by all means let me know what goes wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what went wrong. There was a missing `}` in the line `\rule[-\hfheight+\fracoffset+\hfthickness]{\hfthickness}{\hfheight}`. I've edited the post to fix it; does it work now?